# Installation to internal HD failed (Input/Outut error during read on /dev/sda)

Tags: system-installation, gparted

I received a PC that was running Windows with a boot problem, the automatic recovery program of Windows failed and I couldn't access the PC (I can't access Windows anymore).

I installed Ubuntu with an external hard disk and now I'm running Ubuntu from this external disk and seems to work. Now I would like to install Ubuntu on the internal HD but the installation program shows these messages and errors here:

typed YES
[image: first message]

typed Install now
[image: installation step]

typed continue
[image: second installation message]

[image: first error message]

[image: second error message]

Arrived at this point, I've to quit the installation. I'm new to Ubuntu, I'm not sure if the internal HD works or it's already dead. Trying to find some more information about the internal HD this is what the programs Disks and GParted shows.

Disks Information
[image]

GParted Information
[image]

GParted Warnings
[image]

Thanks already in advance for any advice. I hope that you understand my problem, and I'm sorry for the bad english :)

Comment: In short: the installation target drive is broken beyond repair.

Answer (score 0):

**Considering**

- computer is booted from external USB pen drive(2gb)
- external harddisk(wd passport 2tb) Internal HDD
- 750gb drive is drive where you want install Ubuntu

Disconnect External HDD (wd passport 2tb,)
If we boot from usb flash drive  then other disk won't get mounted until you open file manager
It seems like you went to file manager so target drive got mounted.you can not format

Check target drive is mounted or not
If not mounted run

> fsck.ext4 -cfv /dev/SDA
>   This process will take some time to check  your complete HDD
>   If it asking for fixing  allow it to fix 
>   Then format drive using mkfs.ext4 commond and  run installation wizard

Answer (score 0):

If you are live booting from 2gb usb pendrive.
Unmount external harddisk (2TB WD passport). Considering 740 GB disk is your target disk where you want to install  Ubuntu.Make sure that 740 GB disk (/dev/sda) is unmounted. By default it  should be unmounted.but if you  open file manager it's get mounted.

Once unmount try to check error in disk with following command
if that drive were ext4 earlier

> fsck.ext4  -cfv /dev/sda 
>   If drive were NTFS partition earlier
>   Install ntfs-3g with
>
> sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g

Then run the ntfsfix command on your NTFS partition.

For example:

> ntfsfix /dev/sda

This will scan your entire HDD it may take an hour or two to check error 
Once finished checking it will ask to fix error allow it to fix.